# Как в массиве объектов неизвестной вложенности сменить всем свойство?

Tags: javascript

Как возможно в массиве объектов неизвестной вложенности поменять всем свойство isChange на true?
(вложенность по такой же схеме может быть какая угодно)

```
const items = [
  {
    title: 'Production',
    id: 1,
    isChange: false,
    subTasks: [
      {
        title: 'Production 1',
        id: 2,
        isChange: false,
        subTasks: [{ title: 'Production 1 - 1', id: 3, isChange: false, subTasks: [] }, { title: 'Production 1 - 2', id: 4, isChange: false, subTasks: [] }],
      },
    ],
  },
  {
      title: 'News',
      id: 5,
      isChange: true,
      subTasks: [{ title: 'News 1 - 1', id: 6, isChange: false, subTasks: [] }]
  }
]
```

Буду очень благодарен за помощь!

Comment: Обычная рекурсия ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
const items = [{
    title: 'Production',
    id: 1,
    isChange: false,
    subTasks: [{
      title: 'Production 1',
      id: 2,
      isChange: false,
      subTasks: [{
        title: 'Production 1 - 1',
        id: 3,
        isChange: false,
        subTasks: []
      }, {
        title: 'Production 1 - 2',
        id: 4,
        isChange: false,
        subTasks: []
      }],
    }, ],
  },
  {
    title: 'News',
    id: 5,
    isChange: true,
    subTasks: [{
      title: 'News 1 - 1',
      id: 6,
      isChange: false,
      subTasks: []
    }]
  }
];


function change(tasks) {
  tasks.forEach(task => {
    task.isChange = true;
    if (task.subTasks.length !== 0) {
      change(task.subTasks);
    }
  })
}
change(items);
console.log(items);
```